# Return a list from class (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am writing an app with Entity Framework and I want to return from my table (`champions`) the column `name` - just that column.

In my business layer, I created a class with the method `loadchampions` to call it from my presentation layer. That way, I return the value to display in the datasource from my datagridview.

```
public List<Campeones> LoadChampions()
{
    using (NarachiContext NarachiCTX = new NarachiContext())
    {
        var champions = (from p in NarachiCTX.Campeones 
                         select p.Nombre).ToList();

        return champions;
    }
}
```

I get an error because I am returning a list from type string and I want return a list the type class (this class would be champions). So, I think I could solve the problem. Basically, I want to display the column NAME.

Answer (score 2):

```
var champions = (from p in NarachiCTX.Campeones 
    select p.Nombre).ToList();
```

You're explicitly **telling** it to retrieve a `List<string>`, containing just the names. That's what `select p.Nombre` is saying: For every `Campeones`, get the `Nombre` property, and put it into a list.

If you want to return a `List<Campeones>`, then you should just be able to do this:

```
return NarachiCTX.Campeones.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, sir. But that's not the problem. I just want to return from my class Champions on my datagridview the column "Nombre". If I use that code, I return all the table, I just want to return that column.

For example, this is the colum I want to return and display in my dgv. https://i.imgur.com/jc50gD9.png

Comment: Then change the return type of your method to `List<string>`.  Names are a string, not a Champion.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will be use full to resolve your query.

```
public List<champions> LoadChampions()
{
    using (NarachiContext NarachiCTX = new NarachiContext())
    {
        var champions = NarachiCTX.Campeones.Select(d => new champions
        {
           Name = d.Nombre
        }).ToList();
        return champions;
    }
}
```

Here You must have exist class "champions" having property "Name" with string data type.

```
public class champions
{
     Public string Name;
}
```

we are returning the list of "champions" class.